# Macro : Generate dynamic check boxes for VBA form

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to create checkboxes in a vba form for cell headers ? 
That is all the column header name should be the checkboxes .

For example ..

```
One Two Three   Four
1   2   3       4
1   2   3       4
1   2   3       4
```

In the vba form it should be contain

```
One
Two
Three 
Four
```

as check boxes .. 
Am I expecting right ? or Please explain any other way.. 
Thanks in advance..

Note : there should be no software or tools .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the following code in your UserForm:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim LastColumn  As Long
Dim i           As Long
Dim chkBox      As MSForms.CheckBox

LastColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To LastColumn
    Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & i)
    chkBox.Caption = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i).Value
    chkBox.Left = 5
    chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)
Next i

End Sub
```

You will need to modify the code to suit your specific needs, but that will get you started.

Comment: But it only adds the last column to the form. I expect all the columns to the form..

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in the frmABC module (could be in Sub UserForm_Initialize() or anywheter else you would like this to run):

```
frmABC.chkX.Caption=worksheets("tab_name").range("A2")
```